# Objective C fetch MobileOperator name via Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios-simulator

I have tried fetching carrier name by using the below code via iphone and ipad simulators with XCode7.3.1.But this return (null)

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier  = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];

    // Get carrier name
    carrierName     = [carrier carrierName];
```

Can anyone help me to find carrier name via simulator, without changing XCode system files

Comment: In Simulator you're not connected to cellular network, so `null` is completely expected. You'll have to use a device with active SIM card to get this info.

Comment: i didn't have any apple id to generate device application, Can you suggest me to make carrier info in desktop simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while we fetching the carrier value in the simulator it returns null only(because for carrier value we requires simcard),so we have  to set the carrier value in the info.plist manually,i hope this answer will help you

Comment: how to set info.plist ? can you tell the value?

Answer (score 1):

In Apple [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo?language=objc)

> if a user swaps the device’s SIM card with one from another provider,
>   while your application is running. This class also gives you access to
>   the CTCarrier object, which contains information about the user’s home
>   cellular service provider.

Since simulator doesn't have cellular service provider `carrier` will be nil.

You **need** device with **sim card** inserted to get any value.

Answer (score 0):

No, In simulator it is not possible to get the carrierName. You need device with SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a device to get this info. According to documentation:

> If you configure a device for a carrier and then remove the SIM card,
>   this property retains the name of the carrier. The value for this
>   property is nil if the device was never configured for a carrier.

So `nil` in simulator is an expected return value.